# What is the proper VBA loop for all sheets in an Excel workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I’m trying to change the color of specific columns in every sheet.

However, my code only works for the sheet that is currently active. Which is confusing me because I don’t even specify active sheet in my code.

How do I get this to work for all sheets?

```
Sub rowColors()
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim cell As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    With ws
        LastRow = Range("Q6").End(xlDown).Row
        For Each cell In Range("Q6:Q" & LastRow)
        If cell.Value = "6" Then
            cell.Columns().Interior.Color = RGB(140, 229, 199)
        ElseIf cell.Value = "12" Then
            cell.Columns().Interior.Color = RGB(129, 250, 280)
        ElseIf cell.Value = "20" Then
            cell.Columns().Interior.Color = RGB(129, 250, 260)
        ElseIf cell.Value = "10" Then
            cell.Columns().Interior.Color = RGB(129, 225, 275)
        ElseIf cell.Value = "16" Then
            cell.Columns().Interior.Color = RGB(150, 180, 290)
        End If
        Next
    End With
Next ws

End Sub
```

I’ve also tried taking out the loop and creating a code block for each sheet but it only executes the first one.

Comment: `In .Range("Q6:Q" & LastRow)` you need the dot to reference the `with ws` Same for the lastrow, it is referencing the active sheet.

Comment: Ah! I see. I’m glad I understand the purpose of that now. Thank you.

Comment: [implicit ActiveSheet references](https://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/ImplicitActiveSheetReference) are a very common source of bugs; Rubberduck (free & open-source VBE add-in) can quickly find them all for you.

Comment: Further to above comments, The `ws.Range("Q6").End(xlDown)` returns a `Range` object. You could simply do `Set rng = ws.Range("Q6").End(xlDown)` and then run the loop on `For Each cell in rng.Cells`